# HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder при записи действий создает http request с набором не читаемых символов

Tags: jmeter

Создал текст план состоящий из:

1. Thread group - установил значения 100 пользователей в течении 10 секунд;

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 2. HTTP Request - method "get", protocol "/", Server Name or IP "http://mail.ru", так же в запрос поместил view results in table and graph results;

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 3. HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder - Установил параметры порта, которые соответствуют порту указанному в настройки сети браузера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После записи действий появляется https request следующего содержания:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В результате все 100 запросов возвращаются с ошибкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если вы собираетесь записывать шифрованный траффик - вам следует добавить сертификат JMeter в ваш браузер, файл называется `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`, он генерируется в папке "bin" инсталляции JMeter при запуске [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) (обратите внимание на часть `HTTPS recording and certificates`)
2. Если вы собираетесь тестировать хост `mail.ru` вы не должны включать в тест хост `geotrust.com` поскольку он не имеет никакого отношения к `mail.ru`, то же самое касается всех внешних ресурсов (баннеров, скриптов, стилей, и.т.д.). Если страница вашего сайта содержит [фрейм](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) c видео с Youtube - ваш нагрузочный тест не должен загружать такой фрейм потому что даже если он будет работать медленно - вы ничего не сможете с этим сделать. Вам следует [настроить фильтры в HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) и не записывать запросы к `geotrust.com` и прочим "левым" ресурсам